# how to apply onchange image preview in profile image tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my code I have profile image tag and an input tag for update image.

I want to select a new image `onchange` for update profile picture

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="file" name="userFiles" id="userFiles" class="form-control">
    <div class="text-danger" id="userfile_error" style="display:none;">
    </div>
</div>  
<img width="100" class="img-circle" src="<?php echo base_url() . "User_gallary/" . $user['photo']; ?>" id="myImg">
```

```js
$("#myImg").onchange (function(){
    var x = $('#userFiles').val();
    document.getElementById("myImg").innerHTML = + x;
});
```

Comment: why are you listening to the onchange in the image and not in the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code : -

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('.img-circle').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#myImg").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change .innerHtml property, change .src property.

```
 $("#myImg").onchange (function(){
  var x = $('#userFiles').val();
  document.getElementById("myImg").src = + x;
});
```

Also, there is can be problem with static content (image).